# How to move images and video to SD Card?

Tags: storage

How to move images and videos from internal storage to SD card in Samsung Galaxy S7?

I saw advice to go to

```
My Files -> Images (or other) -> Options -> Select -> All
```

then move. But I can't accept this advice because it looks like flatten directory structure, which I need not to.

**UPDATE**

I want to move files which are created by camera.

**UPDATE 2**

I want BOTH:

1) make camera put NEW images and videos to new location

2) make OLD images be located in new location and be seen by gallery

**UPDATE 3**

So I expect answer suggest either automatic solution, or fully defined manual solution. For example, if solution requires moving files, it should specify BOTH source AND destination directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your advice flattens the directory structure.

Therefore the only thing you can do is:

1. Go to `My Files` -> `My Device`.
2. Navigate to the files/folders you want to move
3. Select the files and folders you want to move
4. Hit `More` -> `Move`
5. Select the destination
6. Hit `Done`
7. Repeat steps 2 - 6 until you are done.

Files from the Camera app are located at `DCIM/Camera/`

For changing the default location of photos and videos, go to the Camera app's settings and change the default location.

Comment: I wan't to move that files, which appears from camera.

Comment: Files from the Camera app are located at DCIM/Camera/

Comment: I want camera put it into new place.

Comment: For changing the default location of photos and videos, go to the Camera app's settings and change the default location.

Comment: I changed camera default location, but it doesn't allow to specify exact directory, it just says "Internal storage" or "SD Card".

Comment: That's correct, the directory will always be `DCIM/Camera` for all stock camera apps (third-party apps may choose a different location but usually also in `DCIM`).

Comment: So, you suggest to move images from `DCIM/Camera` to `DCIM/Camera`? This is equivalent to no-move I guess.

Comment: I suggest the move form `Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera` to `SD Card/DCIM/Camera`